# How can i do a syntax check for shell scripting via github workflows

Tags: shell, syntax-highlighting, github-actions

Basically i need the workflow to check the whole code and should fail if it has any syntax errors.
repo: https://github.com/CyberJalagam/android_rom_building_scripts

Answer (score 0):

Add a step to a workflow that runs on push or PR to `main` to validate syntax:

```yaml
      - name: Validate syntax
        run: bash -n *.sh
```